# Ado.net running SQL Server stored procedure can't retrieve output value when using ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net

```
param.Add(new SqlParameter("@Count", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });

using(var dataset = MsSqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlConn.Conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetList", param.ToArray()))
{
    // Count.Value is not NULL
}

using (SqlDataReader dr = MsSqlHelper.ExecuteReader(SqlConn.Conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetList", param.ToArray()))
{
    // Count.Value is NULL    
}
```

There is an output value in my stored procedure.

If I use `ExecuteReader`, the value of param `Count` is null. But if I change method `ExecuteReader` to `ExecuteDataset`, then I can get value of `Count`.

Why is there no value when I use ExecuteReader?

By the way, nothing has changed in my example except `ExecuteDataset` / `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: The `ExecuteReader` returns a **reader** - which by definition doesn't know how many rows there will be there to be enumerated - so it cannot possibly tell you the count of the rows - it's just a mechanism to **enumerate all rows** .... works as designed, in my opinion

Comment: So I should use `ExecuteDataset`? But isn't it a little bit heavier than `DataReader`?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the output parameter value after the reader has been closed (i.e. after the using block), or after reading to the end of the data.  See [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308621).

Comment: I trid. Reading the value outside the using block, still can't get an value if I use ExecuteReader